# Xcode check score every 5 points

Tags: objective-c

my game is like flappy bird, i have the **int Score = 0** from start. I want to show Ads only when score is 5, 10, 15, 20, and so on, from 5 to 5.

so, i need something like

```
if (score % 5) { //show ads }
```

I tried the line above, but it shows ads all the time, not from 5 to 5.

Any ideas?

Comment: maybe you also need code like `else { [adView hide]; }`

Comment: In the debugger set a breakpoint, single-step, watch the values. `if ((score % 5) == 0) { //show ads }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within an if statement, you are evaluating a boolean expression (true of false). In a boolean expression, a 0 is regarded as false and any other int value will be seen as true.  So (score % 5) will be true when score is 1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,11,... which is the opposite of what you want. This can easily be fixed by either negating the entire expression or by checking when score % 5 == 0.